# Segmentation Error C++

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to the C++ language and I am trying to write a recursive method to traverse a tree. I have a traverse method but there is one line of code that causes a segmentation fault. I have tested this by commenting and uncommenting the line, compiling and executing. I have researched why segmentation errors are caused and do not see why any of what I am doing is causing a problem with the memory. Can someone give me advice about what I am doing wrong?

```
map<int, Node> theNodes;

void initialize()
{
  // first we read the data
  while (inStream.hasNext())
 {
   string nextLine = inStream.nextLine();
   Node newNode = Node(nextLine);
   this->theNodes[newNode.getSequence()] = newNode;
 }
}
```

Code for **getDownLinks()** and **getSequence**

```
vector<int> downLinks;
int sequence;

vector<int> Node::getDownLinks() const
{
    return this->downLinks; //
}

int Node::getSequence() const
{
    return this->sequence;
}
```

Traversal Class Code

```
int totalPayoff;
Node headNode;

int Traversal::traverse()
{

  Node headNode = theNodes[0];
std::vector<int> downLinks = headNode.getDownLinks();
for(int i = 0; i < downLinks.size(); i++)
{
    int a = 0;
    Node currentNode = theNodes[downLinks[i]];
    traverseInner(a, currentNode);
}
return this->totalPayoff;
}
```

Here is the traverseInner function

```
int Traversal::traverseInner(int& level, Node& node)
{

std::vector<int> nodeDownLinks = node.getDownLinks();

if(nodeDownLinks.size() == 0)
{
    totalPayoff = totalPayoff + node.getPayoff();
    return 0;
}

    for(int i = 0; i < nodeDownLinks.size(); i++)
    {
       int a = 0;
       Node currentNode = theNodes[nodeDownLinks[i]]; <-- This causes segmentation error.
       traverseInner(a, currentNode);
    }


return totalPayoff;
}
```

Any variables that are not declared here are declared in the header file. The code compiles fine.

I'd also like to mention that I have written this code in many different ways and through my observations have come to the conclusion that any variable that is trying to be accessed in the braces of a nested statement cannot be accessed by the memory. Even the **int a** variable that is declared right above the problem statement and even hard coded data which is supposed to be there such as **nodeDownLinks**. If I try to print out through standard output the size of the vector inside one of the nested statements, I also get a segmentation error.

Comment: `getDownLinks()` if this returns a member and not a local variable, you could return it by const reference, and store the result as `const std::vector<int>& downLinks` if you don't need to modify it. This will save copying the vector.

Comment: Did you try running it through GDB?  Can you post the code of `node.getDownLinks()`?

Comment: Where is `theNodes` initialized or filled? It's obvious you're trying to access an out of bounds index there.

Comment: have you tested if you got the segmentation fault accessing nodeDownLinks[0] for example, immediately after getting the "nodeDownLinks" ?

Comment: @Drewen yes, the **nodeDownLinks** size is greater than zero because it is trying to run the code that is inside the for loop. Also I have printed out inside the for loop while testing, meaning the size of that vector is greater than 0.

Comment: Please post a MCVE not disjointed snippets.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have done as you requested. Is there anything you can see that you can help me with?

Comment: Someone is more likely to help you if you post a single block of code, stripped of irrelevant parts, which shows the issue. I am lazy. If I can copy and paste it into my compiler in one step, I may debug it for you. But not 2 steps.

Comment: @superuserdo: I don't see an MCVE.

Comment: @NeilKirk the code is a lot bigger than this. The very trivial beginning steps require use of a custom Utils directory which I would have to also provide if you wish to copy and paste into your compiler. If i tried to make this one block of code with a Main, it would not compile ideally without these Util classes. What I have provided shows the basic steps after the Utils class has done its work.

Comment: Fake the inputs needed until you can reproduce in a single block of code.

Comment: Post an MCVE. Not your whole real program. Not little snippets. An MCVE.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It should have been one of your very first debugging steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the value inside "nodeDownLinks[i]" it is not initialized, having a memory random value, then you are trying to access this position in the 
"theNodes" array and gives to you the segmentation fault.

Please, be sure the values inside "nodeDownLinks" are initialized.

Comment: The value inside of **nodeDownLinks** is an integer. Could it be possible that this still is the problem?

Comment: yes, be sure always having the values initialized, for example, to zero

Comment: I just tested your advice. I printed out the size of nodeDownLinks (which was 3) outside of the for loop. Then in the for loop I printed out the nodeDownLinks[i] and a Segmentation Error happened again. I commented out all other code in the for loop. Is the for loop the problem? It seems to be.

Comment: maybe is because you are creating a copy of the first node:

Node currentNode = theNodes[downLinks[i]];
Please, test Node& currentNode = theNodes[downLinks[i]];

Comment: I commented out this code when I ran the last test and it still happened

Comment: Maybe is because you are creating a copy of the nodes in the first "for loop":

Node currentNode = theNodes[downLinks[i]];

Please, test the following:

Node& currentNode = theNodes[downLinks[i]];

Comment: I just tested and I thought this was the answer but still the problem persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72286/discussion-between-drewen-and-superuserdo).

Answer (score 0):

99% it crashes because `theNodes` has less size, then `nodeDownLinks[i]` contains index. So nodeDownLinks[i] contains wrong index, u'd better check it and print what goes wrong this way:

```
   int a = 0;
   int link = nodeDownLinks[i];
   if (theNodes.size() <= link)
       std::err << "Wrong link " << link << " in Node" << std::endl; 
   else
       traverseInner(a, theNodes[link]);
```

It shouldnt crash and you can find wrong index in `nodeDownLink` easily!